# Secure version control

Tags: security, version-control

I would like to have your opinion about the subject "version control",
but focusing on security.

Some common features:

- allowing to access to source code using clients *only*
  (no way to access the source code on the server directly)
- granting permission to access only the
  source code which I am allowed to modify  (i.e.: a developer should be able
  to access the source code related to his project only).
  So it should be possible to create user groups and granting different
  levels of access.
- tracking modifications, check-ins, and check-outs and the
  developers who made them...
- ...and, surely, I am forgetting something.

Which are the most "paranoid" version control systems that you know?
Which features do they implement?

My aim is creating an enviroment for developing applications managing sensible data: credit cards, passwords, and so on...
A malicious developer may insert backdoor or intentionally alter some security features. So the access to the source code should be controlled strictly.
I must confess that my knowledge of version control systems is poor, so, I fear, customizing SVN could be a hard task for me.

Thanks

Comment: Pretty much every version control system out there implements the security you mentioned, and usually much more.  What is the purpose for your question?

Comment: not that many track checkouts.

Comment: Perforce tracks checkouts, but gbjbaanb is right. Few version control systems have strong security controls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Perforce](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/finance/index.html) is widely used in the Finance Industry where security of code is sometimes an issue.

You can setup gatekeepers and access controls to restrict visibility of code and produce audit trails for various activities for SOX compliance.

Comment: Agreed. While I'm not a big fan of Perforce, it's the only one I've used that can do most of these things. Clearcase lacks the granularity, and most opensource tools (cvs, svn, hg, git) are weak around it because they focus on opensource projects. For good audit functions and granular access control, I'd definitely go with p4, much as it drives me crazy as a user.

Comment: @Rob Napier: I agree - given the choice, I'd go with an open source distributed version control system. But if the main requirements are audit-ability and security, Perforce is what I'd recommend. Of course, would happily switch if hg, git or Bazzar get the equivalent functionality!

Answer (score 2):

I know that the ones you want are *not* the ones you want. For example, Clearcase or Serena Dimensions can do all the above... but you'd be bonkers to want to use them. (ah, I hear you say, I'm the admin so I don;t have to take that pain. Well, these also require lots of care and attention - we had 8 Clearcase admins at the last company I worked for. You don't want the nightmare of continually helping users with them).

So. You can have the horrible ones, or you could just use the friendly, easy-to-use SVN and implement your own checkout-tracking (using http transport and Apache logs), and slap access control permissions on every directory. You'd also have to secure the end-repository on disc, but you have to do this with every SCM, even something like Dimensions stores its database in Oracle - if you had access to Oracle instance, you could fiddle with the saved bits, so you have to secure that anyway.

Comment: In Clearcase, you can't control vob-level mounting and reading(that's a major issue at my workplace). Version...8? 7.1? will introduce that.

Comment: @Paul, agreed. Clearcase has very limited control over access. Not just vob-level mounting, but it's very hard to control what users can see within a vob; generally you have to use unix groups, which are notoriously limited and difficult to enforce.

Answer (score 1):

[Perforce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perforce) has those features and is a really good product imho.

Comment: Really? We used to use p4 at work and had to deal with slow repositories, sluggish response during checkpointing, poor integration tracking etc. I feel that it depends too much on the power of the machine that's hosting the server since it does almost everything there.

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim Do you have any suggestion over Perforce and other tools such as SVN, ClearCase, etc...? I confused and couldn't find useful, secure and optimum version control software.

Comment: I've moved to git completely for professional and personal work.

Answer (score 1):

Use a well-known, industry standard system like [subversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn-book.html). It can control access to individual projects very simply, and using the web server authz configuration can control individual access to specific files in each project.

The only non-stanard issue is logging check-outs. But the web server can easily log this information for you.

Your users will thank you.

Answer (score 0):

github is a wrapper for git which provides these features for git server.  Compared to raw git servers, it notably includes access control, and it also has useful web interfaces to the code for authorised users.